# GPRS Shield 1.0 Auto Shutdown and others

Tags: embedded, arduino, wifi, gprs

I have Questions with a extensive board

http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/GPRS_Shield_V1.0

If my current supply maxium is 200mA, in spec. its max is 450. When it wants to register to APN at low signal place, will it auto poweroff?

BTW, anyone knows what wifi module like this `GPRS_Shield` has built-in socket can be used by UART, except `Wifi_Shield`

ps: I dont use Arduino, I'am using BeagleBone

Comment: Many (bad) things can happen. If shield requires 450mA, no less than it must be available.

Comment: I have tried to use external DC supply, 5V1A, but After I use it, my UART can't action.(I use minicom) Is it will change some kind of parameter after High current supply?

Comment: Strangely, I use BeagleBone another supply port : VDD_5V(1A), it can work... Autopoweroff testing.